# What is the cost of the Python APIs in C++ software?

Tags: c++, python, api

I was trying some Python APIs maded for some C++ calls and I see no decrease in performance. Actually, I think that the equivalent application written only in C++ is a little bit slower/laggish.

In particular, I was trying [Pyside](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide) and some QT application in C++.

Now I know that GUIs love languages that have a good support for dynamic bindings, but I don't know too much about Python internals: is there some explanation for the reason why a Pyside application is at least as fast as the C++ equivalent ?

If I offer Python APIs inside my C++ program, what will the costs be? One more indirection?

P.S.
Does python offer some native Windowing framework for cross-platform development?

Comment: PySide is a really thin wrapper around the C library. Too thin, IMHO - it's essentially just exposing the functions, so it doesn't feel like a Python library at all.

Comment: @Lattyware i'm talking about APIs here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the risk of being downvoted, I'm going to provide a very crude, somewhat subjective hypothesis.

QT, while being very general-purpose, doesn't exactly provide a blazing fast GUI API. Its level of abstraction has quite a cost. We're talking about a heap allocation per widget, per layout, etc. Just have a look at QListWidget and the fact that QListWidgetItem in itself is a separately allocated, fairly complex object. I once had to profile a developer's code -- the logic was suspected to be slow, but I found that almost the entire 6 seconds it took for the operation was spent creating a QListWidget with thousands of list entries. This was in C++.

My thoughts on this, without seeing your code and usage of QT, is that the overall overhead of the QT GUI makes the differences between a language like C++ and Python negligible.

Now what isn't so debatable is that the productivity of using QT through Python is dramatically greater than using it in C++ where we have to deal with the MOC with preprocessed signals and slots, etc. You might want to focus on that more than the performance differences of using a GUI framework in one language vs another.

> PS Does python offers some native Windowing framework for
>   cross-platform development ?

http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming

Comment: That's why real programmers use virtual lists. *runs*

Comment: I would basically agree with this.  If the majority of the instructions that are getting executed are in QT, then it doesn't make that much difference what your business-logic is written in.  Your just not going to see that much of a difference.

Comment: so only binding when it comes to the GUI world under Python ?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams as far as i know virtual lists are only for windows, i need a cross platform solution.

Comment: Every widget toolkit has a virtual list implementation if you look hard enough.